# MongoDB count occurrences of each value from a group filtered set of documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to write a MongoDB query to get the result that returns
daily count amount of success and failure in 'passcheck' field.

below is my database schema and query that I am writing

| field | value |
| --- | --- |
| createdAt | YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS.sssZ Before/after noon - String |
| passCheck | success or failure - String |

```
db.getCollection('integrated_transaction_logs').aggregate([

 { $group: {
     "_id": {
         "year": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 0, 4 ]}, 
         "month": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 5, 2 ]}, 
         "day": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 8, 2 ]}, 
         "passCheck": "$passCheck"
     },
     "count": {$sum: 1}
     
   }
 },
  {$sort:{_id:1}},
  //{$count: "counted"} ]);
```

what I got by a query above is like this,

```
  {
"_id" : {
    "year" : "2020",
    "month" : "11",
    "day" : "17",
    "passCheck" : "success"
},
"count" : 1.0}
{
"_id" : {
    "year" : "2020",
    "month" : "12",
    "day" : "18",
    "passCheck" : "failure"
},
"count" : 1.0}
{
"_id" : {
    "year" : "2020",
    "month" : "12",
    "day" : "18",
    "passCheck" : "success"
},
"count" : 2.0}
```

is there any tip or advice that I can get the result like this?

```
"_id" : {
    "year" : "202X",
    "month" : "XX",
     "day" : "XX",
     "passCheck" : "success"},
     "Success_count" : X.0,
     "failure_count" : X.0
}
```

enter code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you group by passCheck aslo, the result would be either success or failure. So whay=t you can do is, you can use a condition using `$cond`

```
{ $group: {
     "_id": {
         "year": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 0, 4 ]}, 
         "month": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 5, 2 ]}, 
         "day": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 8, 2 ]}
     },
     "success_count": {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [{$eq: ["$passCheck", "success"]},1,0]
        }
      },
      "failure_count": {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [ { $eq: ["$passCheck", "failure" ]},1,0]
        }
      }       
   }
},
{
    "$addFields": {
      "_id.failure_count": "$failure_count",
      "_id.success_count": "$success_count",
      "failure_count": "$$REMOVE",
      "success_count": "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Lxb75yLinYv)**